# why i can't load 2 forms in one page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need load 2 forms in one page and for mapping URL, I must add the path('',.........) for 2 forms. but how I can do that?
if add path(''.....) for 2 forms, its add one of my forms not both on the same path. how I can do that?

I tried this :

```py
urlpatterns=[
         path('',views.register,name='register')
         path('',views.login,name='login')

]
```

because I need to load this 2 forms in one page in another word in index path, but when I run​the server I see one of these forms, not both.

Comment: there is nothing with the url, everything depends on your view. and how you are going to display both forms in template and get data in the view

Comment: how i can handel that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a view and include both forms in the context.

```
class TwoFormView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['form1'] = UserForm()
        ctx['form2'] = RegistrationForm()
        return ctx
```

you can call this with

```
path('two-form-view/', views.TowFormView.as_view(), name="two-form-view"),
```

**EDIT**

in the post

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    # do something
else: 
    # add forms to context and render template again
```

Comment: in other word, I have a template that has 2 popup section, register, and log in. I need load register and login in that 2 popup menu .

Comment: Which is what this does for you

Comment: how I can access these form in the template ? {{ ctx[1] }} ?

Comment: `{{ form1 }}` and `{{ form2 }}`

Comment: mate .what  if i need work with 2 forms , like check if form1.is_valid() or etc what id can do ? because in this state i can only load form but i can't have any work on that form .

Comment: or in register form, i need use: form.save() or other work. what I do that with this method you said?

Comment: if `form2` is the registration form, use `form2.save()`

Comment: where i can add form2.save() ? i have other options work with form2 for example : if form2.is_valid() : form2.save() . i dont know where i need put this form2.save() in class base view

Comment: within the view you're posting to

Comment: i dont have any view , i create 2 form and pass 2 form in that class you said above , i must wirte view for 2 form ? im confusing and dont have idea what i do, please help me

Comment: Do you mean : class view that i have passed to it 2 form ? If yes , where how i can add form.save() ?